# How AM-GM is applied here

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

[image]

I don't understand how AM-GM is applied in the last part of the picture. This is on the the $16^{th}$ page of the book in chapter $1$ about $AM-GM$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+c}{a+d}\geq\frac{4(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}$$ or
$$(a+b+c+d)\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+d}\right)\geq4,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$(a+b+c+d)\left(\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+d}\right)\geq2\sqrt{(b+c)(a+d)}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{(b+c)(a+d)}}=4.$$
The second inequality we can prove by the same way.

I think a proof by C-S and after this by AM-GM is much more better.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. After reading more pages, the book turns out to give the proofs 'indirectly' like yours. I thought it was straightforward $AM-GM$.

Comment: @GhostTown I believe you're reading Pham's Secrets in Inequalities book. If so, they at times skip steps, but generally there is enough information to tease it out. I would not recommend this book for someone that's mostly new to inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+c}{a+d}}2\geq\frac2{\frac{b+c}{a+c}+\frac{a+d}{a+c}}\quad(\because AM\ge HM)$$
Proceed similarly for the next term.